# Join (custom) query in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm making a Book Store Application using Spring Boot and Spring
 Data. I need support to know if what I have done is right way or not.

I'm making a Book Store REST Application using Spring Boot and Spring Data. I have just started with it and got stuck at a point. Though I have achieved(custom query - join) what I wanted but I really would like to know if what I have done is the right way or there is better approach for it.

Here are the three entity classes:

Book:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Book_Details")
    public class Book {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="CUSTOM_SEQUENCE")
        @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "customer_seq", allocationSize = 1, name = "CUSTOM_SEQUENCE")
        @Column(name="BookId")
        int bookId;

        public int getBookId() {
            return bookId;
        }

        public void setBookId(int bookId) {
            this.bookId = bookId;
        }

        @Column(name="BookName")
        String bookName;

        @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="authorId")
        Author author;

        @Column(name="Language")
        String language;

        @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="genreId")
        Genre genre;

        @Column(name="GoodReadReviews")
        String goodReadReviews;

    //To display values
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "BookId=" + this.bookId + "::BookName=" + this.bookName + 
          "::AuthorId=" + this.author.authorName + 
                    "::Langauge = " + this.language + "::GenreId = " + 
            this.genre.genreName + "::GoodReadReviews=" + 
           this.goodReadReviews;

        }



        public String getBookName() {
            return bookName;
        }

        public void setBookName(String bookName) {
            this.bookName = bookName;
        }


        public String getLanguage() {
            return language;
        }

        public void setLanguage(String language) {
            this.language = language;
        }


        public String getGoodReadReviews() {
            return goodReadReviews;
        }

        public void setGoodReadReviews(String goodReadReviews) {
            this.goodReadReviews = goodReadReviews;
        }

        public Author getAuthor() {
            return author;
        }

        public void setAuthor(Author author) {
            this.author = author;
        }

        public Genre getGenre() {
            return genre;
        }

        public void setGenre(Genre genre) {
            this.genre = genre;
        }


    }
```

Author:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Author_Details")
    public class Author {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
        generator="AuthorSeqGenerator")
        @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "author_seq", allocationSize = 1, name 
        = "AuthorSeqGenerator")
        @Column(name="AuthorId")
        int authorId;

        @Column(name="AuthorName")
        String authorName;

        @Column(name="Country")
        String country;

        @Column(name="Gender")
        String gender;

        @OneToOne(mappedBy="author")
        @JoinColumn(name="authorId")
        private Book book;

        public Book getBook() {
            return book;
        }
        public void setBook(Book book) {
            this.book = book;
        }
        public int getAuthorId() {
            return authorId;
        }
        public void setAuthorId(int authorId) {
            this.authorId = authorId;
        }


        public String getAuthorName() {
            return authorName;
        }
        public void setAuthorName(String authorName) {
            this.authorName = authorName;
        }
        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }
        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }
        public String getGender() {
            return gender;
        }
        public void setGender(String gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }

    }
```

Genre:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Genre_details")
    public class Genre {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
        generator="GenreSeqGenerator")
        @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "genre_seq", allocationSize = 1, name = 
        "GenreSeqGenerator")
        int genreId;

        @Column(name="GenreName")
        String genreName;

        @OneToOne(mappedBy="genre")
        private Book book;

        public Book getBook() {
            return book;
        }

        public void setBook(Book book) {
            this.book = book;
        }

        public int getGenreId() {
            return genreId;
        }

        public void setGenreId(int genreId) {
            this.genreId = genreId;
        }




        public String getGenreName() {
            return genreName;
        }

        public void setGenreName(String genreName) {
            this.genreName = genreName;
        }

    }
```

Below is the main Spring-boot application class:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class BookStoreManagerApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(BookStoreManagerApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Autowired
        DataSource dataSource;

        @Autowired
        BookRepository bookRepository;



        //@Transactional(readOnly=true)
        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

            System.out.println("DATASOURCE = " + dataSource);

            System.out.println("1.) Find By Book Id = " );
            for(Book book:bookRepository.findByBookId(1)) {
                System.out.println(book.toString());
            }

            System.out.println("2.) Find By Book Name = ");
            for(Book book:bookRepository.findByBookName("Pinjar")) {
                System.out.println(book.toString());
            }
System.out.println("3.) Find All = " );
            for(Book book:bookRepository.findAll()) {
                System.out.println(book.toString());
            }

            System.out.println("4.) Custom Query using @Query annotation = " );
            for(Object[] joinResult: bookRepository.findByAuthorIdAndGenreId(1, 1)){
                System.out.println(joinResult[0] + "::" + joinResult[1] + "::" + 
                        "::" + joinResult[2] + "::" + joinResult[3] + "::" + joinResult[4] +
                        "::" + joinResult[5] + "::" + joinResult[6] + "::" + joinResult[7]);
            }


            System.out.println("Check if tables are created!");
        }


    }
```

Here is the Book Repository:

```
    public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, String>{

        List<Book> findByBookId(int id);

        //List<Book> findByAuthorId(int authorId);

        List<Book> findByLanguage(String lang);

        //List<Book> findByGenreId(int genreId);

        List<Book> findByGoodReadReviews(String reviews);

        List<Book> findByBookName(String bookName);

        List<Book> findAll();

        //Stream<Book> findAllByStream();

        @Query("select b.bookId, b.bookName, a.authorId, a.authorName, b.language, "
                + "g.genreId, g.genreName,b.goodReadReviews from Book b, Author a, "
                + "Genre g where b.author=a.authorId and b.genre=g.genreId and "
                + "a.authorId=?1 and g.genreId=?2")
        List<Object[]> findByAuthorIdAndGenreId(int authorId, int genreId);

    }
```

This entire thing is working fine but for the above join query using
 @Query annotation I want to know if this is the right approach or I
 can use some better approach. I'm sorry for the naive-ness of this
 question.

The result is as follows:

```
    1.) Find By Book Id =
    2019-01-22 17:02:40 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select book0_.book_id as book_id1_1_, book0_.author_id as author_id5_1_, book0_.book_name as book_name2_1_, book0_.genre_id as genre_id6_1_, book0_.good_read_reviews as good_read_reviews3_1_, book0_.language as language4_1_ from book_details book0_ where book0_.book_id=?
    BookId=1::BookName=Tuesdays With Morrie::AuthorId=null::Langauge = English::GenreId = null::GoodReadReviews=4.5
    2.) Find By Book Name =
    2019-01-22 17:02:40 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select book0_.book_id as book_id1_1_, book0_.author_id as author_id5_1_, book0_.book_name as book_name2_1_, book0_.genre_id as genre_id6_1_, book0_.good_read_reviews as good_read_reviews3_1_, book0_.language as language4_1_ from book_details book0_ where book0_.book_name=?
    BookId=2::BookName=Pinjar::AuthorId=null::Langauge = Punjabi::GenreId = null::GoodReadReviews=4.8
    3.) Find All =
    2019-01-22 17:02:40 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select book0_.book_id as book_id1_1_, book0_.author_id as author_id5_1_, book0_.book_name as book_name2_1_, book0_.genre_id as genre_id6_1_, book0_.good_read_reviews as good_read_reviews3_1_, book0_.language as language4_1_ from book_details book0_
    BookId=1::BookName=Tuesdays With Morrie::AuthorId=null::Langauge = English::GenreId = null::GoodReadReviews=4.5
    BookId=2::BookName=Pinjar::AuthorId=null::Langauge = Punjabi::GenreId = null::GoodReadReviews=4.8
    BookId=3::BookName=Raavi Paar::AuthorId=null::Langauge = Hindi::GenreId = null::GoodReadReviews=4.6
    4.) Custom Query using @Query annotation =
    2019-01-22 17:02:40 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select book0_.book_id as col_0_0_, book0_.book_name as col_1_0_, author1_.author_id as col_2_0_, author1_.author_name as col_3_0_, book0_.language as col_4_0_, genre2_.genre_id as col_5_0_, genre2_.genre_name as col_6_0_, book0_.good_read_reviews as col_7_0_ from book_details book0_ cross join author_details author1_ cross join genre_details genre2_ where book0_.author_id=author1_.author_id and book0_.genre_id=genre2_.genre_id and author1_.author_id=? and genre2_.genre_id=?
    1::Tuesdays With Morrie::::1::Mitch Albom::English::1::Fiction::4.5
```

Comment: Maybe you should ask here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay! Thank you @Pijotrek

Comment: It looks OK, however instead of using the untyped `Object[]` read about using a Spring Data projection interface instead https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections The benefit is, is you don't have to do all the object mapping yourself, and you'll have an understandable type.

Comment: Thank you @AlexB, I'll read about it.